# Intersection Solutions of four nonlinear equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, mathematical-software

I have four nonlinear equations I want to find the points of intersection of these equations, and I used the software Mathematica, unfortunately after many hours of waiting it does not give  me any result
Do you have an idea how to solve this kind of problem?.

My equations are the following

1)  $(52 \alpha ^2+\alpha  (104 \beta +440 \sqrt{3}-1071)+\beta (65 \beta
   +110 \sqrt{3}-752)-2 (52 \gamma +55 \sqrt{3}-376) \delta +(-52 \gamma -440 \sqrt{3}+1071) \gamma -65 \delta ^2)=0$

2)     $52 \alpha ^2+\alpha (-52 \beta +80 \sqrt{3}-450)+2 \beta (13 \beta +10
   \sqrt{3}+38)-52 \gamma ^2+\gamma (52 \delta -80 \sqrt{3}+450)-2 \delta (13
   \delta +10 \sqrt{3}+38)=0$

3) $\beta ^2-\alpha ^3=0$

4) $\delta ^2-\gamma ^3=0$

Comment: Where do those equations come from $-$ i.e. why do you care about
this particular system with its complicated coefficients?
$$ $$
(3) and (4) mean that $(\alpha,\beta) = (x^2, x^3)$ and
$(\gamma,\delta) = (y^2, y^3)$ for some $x,y$.
So now you have two equations in two variables
and can use a resultant to eliminate one of them.
Then you still have to deal with the $\sqrt 3$'s in the coefficients,
though some packages know how to do this.

Comment: I need to solve this system of equation to prove that it has only two solutions, I used Mathematica software but it's very complicated

Comment: Again I ask: why is this particular system of equations of interest,
and in what context do you "need to solve" it? 
Knowing where a problem comes from (and why you expect that
it has only two (real? complex?) solutions) is often useful in finding a solution $-$
and also in motivating others to help you with it.

Comment: I have two differential linear systems with centers the first one has a first integral H1(x,y)=k, the second one has the first integral H2(x,y)=h, I am looking for the number of intersection points between H1(x,y)=k, H2(x,y)=h, and the curve y^2-x^3=0......I suppose that there are two  pairs (\alpha, \beta) and  (\gamma, \delta) satisfying the four following equations .(it is necessary)....................1) H1(\alpha, \beta) =H1(\gamma, \delta) ....2) H2(\alpha, \beta) =H2(\gamma, \delta)     ...3)  \beta^2-\alpha^3=0 ............4) \delta^2-\gamma^3=0.

Comment: The most straightforward way is by computing resultants. If $P, Q$ are polynomials in $x, y, z, \ldots$, then Resultant[P, Q, x] gives a polynomial in $y, z, \ldots$, which vanishes at $(y_0, z_0, \ldots)$ if and only if there exists some $x_0$, such that $(x_0, y_0, \ldots)$ is a common zero of $P$ and $Q$. Thus you can pass from a system of $n$ equations in $n$ variables to a system of $n-1$ equations in $n-1$ variables. Unfortunately the degree increases, so in this case it would be wise to exploit (3) and (4) as Noam Elkies described first.

Comment: What was edited in your question? Please notice it.

Comment: After that edit https://www.dropbox.com/s/mkvvskm0i0m5mtx/screen26.12.2018.docx?dl=0 the question was edited one more time without any notice. This is not a good practice.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem ..you answered to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expansion of the comment by Noam D. Elkies. Indeed, we can rewrite your equations 3) and 4) as $(\alpha,\beta)=(x^2,x^3)$ and $(\gamma,\delta)=(y^2,y^3)$ for some $x,y$. Substituting into eqs. 1) and 2) these expressions of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ in terms of $x,y$, we reduce your system of four eqs. to that of the following two: $P_1=0=P_2$, where $P_1,P_2$ are certain polynomials in $x,y$.

The resultant $\text{Res}_y(P_1,P_2)$ vanishes iff, for a given value of $x$, the polynomials $P_1,P_2$ have a common root $y$. We find that $\text{Res}_y(P_1,P_2)=0=\text{Res}_x(P_1,P_2)$ identically for all $x$ and $y$. So, $P_1$ and $P_2$ need some preliminary cleaning. Indeed, we see that 
\begin{equation}
 Q_1:=\frac{P_1}{y-x},\quad Q_2:=\frac{P_2}{2(y-x)}
\end{equation}
are polynomials in $x,y$. Thus, 
\begin{equation}
 \text{$(x,x)$ is a solution to our system for any complex $x$.} \tag{*}
\end{equation}

The resultants $R_y:=\text{Res}_y(Q_1,Q_2)$ and $R_x:=\text{Res}_x(Q_1,Q_2)$ are polynomials in $x$ and in $y$, respectively, each having $16$ distinct complex roots, say $x_1,\dots,x_{16}$ for $R_y$ and $y_1,\dots,y_{16}$ for $R_x$. Details of all calculations here, as well as the particular enumeration of $x_1,\dots,x_{16}$ and $y_1,\dots,y_{16}$, can be seen in the [Mathematica notebook](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZICnC7ZUdC9JGUcYuHwFWWjU1GDa5sxkW0k) or its [pdf image](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZACnC7ZIYL4DHRMyJmg2WOQYWe9vmmIL52y).

So, for each $i\in[16]:=\{1,\dots,16\}$ there is at least one $j\in[16]$ such that the pair $(x_i,y_j)$ is a solution to the system $Q_1=0=Q_2$. Moreover, it is easy to see that for each $i\in[16]\setminus\{3\}$, there is at most one (and therefore the only one) $j=j_i\in[16]$ such that the pair $(x_i,y_{j_i})$ is a solution to the system $Q_1=0=Q_2$. The corresponding pairs $(i,j_i)$ are $(1, 3), (2, 4), (4, 2), (5, 6), (6, 5), (7, 11), (8, 12), (9, 10), (10, 9), (11, 7)$, $(12, 8), (13, 14), (14, 13), (15, 16), (16, 15)$. For the exceptional value $i=3$, we have at most two values of $j\in[16]$ (namely, $j=1$ and $j=3$) such that the pairs $(x_3,y_j)$ may be solutions to the system $Q_1=0=Q_2$; in fact we see that these pairs $(x_3,y_j)$, equal $(0,\sqrt3)$ and $(0,0)$, are indeed solutions to the system $Q_1=0=Q_2$; the pair $(0,0)$ has already been accounted for by (*).

Thus, we have described all the $16$ pairs $(x,y)$ that are (in addition to the "trivial" pairs given by (*)) solutions to the system $Q_1=0=Q_2$. All these solutions $(x,y)$ are now straightforward to transcribe into a complete set of solutions $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$ of the original system.

Comment: You mean that the solution is (0,0,3, 3 (3)^(1/2))......I don't know hwo I can thank you....Thanks a lot sir  for your help

Comment: Solving numerically the original system, both Maple and Mathematica produce 13 different real solutions. Taking into account multiplicity, Mathematica counts 18 solutions (in particular, zero solution is of multiplicity 4 and the solution $(2.45653,  -3.85019,  0.,  0.)$ is of multiplicity 2 and the solution $(3., 5.19615,  0.,  0.)$ is of multiplicity 2).

Comment: @user64494 : How can solving numerically ensure that, among other things, you got all the solutions?

Comment: Here https://www.dropbox.com/s/6exiv40yikocwg5/sys.pdf?dl=0 is the result obtained with Mathematica and here https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqdh72m3cg8lwtg/sys%20in%20maple.pdf?dl=0 is the result in Maple. The DirectSearch is one of the best numerical solvers in the world.

Comment: Solving numerically the system from the edited question https://www.dropbox.com/s/mkvvskm0i0m5mtx/screen26.12.2018.docx?dl=0, I obtain that the solution set is infinite (see https://www.dropbox.com/s/ul0u4wxzxuyv2jx/modifiedsys.pdf?dl=0 ).

Comment: @user64494 : The many obvious questions about numerical solutions, one of them stated in my previous comment, still remain.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any complete solution in your answer.

Comment: @user64494 : Why? The claim in my answer was that we have a complete set of solutions, and a detailed proof of that claim was given.  Do you see any defect in the proof?

Comment: If I correctly understand it, you claim a finite set of the solutions whereas the NSolve command https://www.dropbox.com/s/ul0u4wxzxuyv2jx/modifiedsys.pdf?dl=0 claims an infinite set of the solutions. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @user64494 : I certainly did not claim that the set of all solutions is finite. I only claimed that the set of all "nontrivial" solutions is finite, and this was proved. On the other hand, the set of "trivial" solutions of the form $(x,x)$ for complex $x$ is obviously infinite. As for numerical solvers, one cannot trust any part of their output without rigorous additional examination -- basically, you still need a rigorous proof. So, it may actually be much easier to re-check the proof already given in my answer.

Comment: Can you kindly describe the solutions of the system from the question which correspond your "the set of "trivial" solutions of the form $(x,x)$ for complex $x$ ", basing your claim?

Comment: @user64494 : As follows immediately from my answer, the "trivial" solutions $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$ of the original system are of the form $(x^2,x^3,x^2,x^3)$ for complex $x$. The representative given in your file https://www.dropbox.com/s/ul0u4wxzxuyv2jx/modifiedsys.pdf?dl=0 is in this set of solutions, up to some rounding -- corresponding to $x\approx-0.76577$. Is there still something in my answer that makes you not quite happy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87527/discussion-between-user64494-and-iosif-pinelis).